# What does `{{{variable}}}` mean in handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

What does triple curly braces mean in handlebars template syntax?

For example

```
{{{variable}}}
```

I cannot find any documentation.

Thanks

Comment: http://assemble.io/docs/Pages-Collections.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Because it was originally designed to generate HTML, Handlebars escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", `{{{`.

Source: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping
Found via: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars-site/issues/28