# Handlebars not rendering html on Node.js

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I am new developing with node.js and I could not make handlebars render the html for my code.
Both my addOEdit.hbs and list.hbs are not being rendered as html.

It is rendering the html itself as a text. I tried to all dependencies are installed. Like this:

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI61Q.png)

My index.js file:

```
require("./models/db");

//Initializing dependencies
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const handlebars = require("handlebars");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const {
  allowInsecurePrototypeAccess,
} = require("@handlebars/allow-prototype-access");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const studentController = require("./controllers/StudentController");

//initializing app
const app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server up and running on port 3000");
});

//Home page
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
        <h2>Welcome to the students database</h2>
        <h3>Click here to get access to the <b> <a href="/student/list">Database</a></b></h3>`);
});

//Setting Handlebars
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views/"));
app.engine(
  "hbs",
  exphbs.engine({
    handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(handlebars),
    extname: "hbs",
    defaultLayout: "mainLayout",
    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts/",
  })
);

app.use("/student", studentController);
```

My studentcontroller:

```
const express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Student = mongoose.model("Student");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("student/addOrEdit", {
    viewTitle: "Insert Student",
  });
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.id == "") {
    insertRecord(req, res);
  } else {
    updateRecord(req, res);
  }
});

function insertRecord(req, res) {
  var student = new Student();
  student.fullName = req.body.fullName;
  student.email = req.body.email;
  student.mobile = req.body.email;
  student.city = req.body.city;
  student.save((err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect("student/list");
    } else {
      console.log("Error during insert: " + err);
    }
  });
}

function updateRecord(req, res) {
  Student.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: req.body._id },
    req.body,
    { new: true },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.redirect("student/list");
      } else {
        console.log("Error during update: " + err);
      }
    }
  );
}

//Listing all students
router.get("/list", (req, res) => {
  Student.find((err, docs) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("student/list", {
        list: docs,
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Error retrieving the list: " + err);
    }
  });
});

//Get student by id
router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Student.findById(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render("student/addOrEdit", {
        viewTitle: "Update Student",
        student: doc,
      });
      console.log(doc);
    }
  });
});

//Delete student
router.get("delte/:id", (req, res) => {
  Student.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect("student/list");
    } else {
      console.log("Error in deletion: " + err);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Main Layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Students</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <style>
    #box { background-color: #fff; margin-top: 25px; padding: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); box-shadow: 10px
    10px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.75); border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius:
    10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border: 0px solid #000000; }
  </style>

  <body class="bg-info">
    <div id="box" class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What do your `mainLayout` look like?

Comment: @76484 just edited the main post

Comment: Try `{{{body}}}` (three braces on each side). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31496795/3397771

Comment: Can't believe I didnt realise it! Thank you so much @76484